# Selenium find by Xpath and Text

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Trying to select a div by the text inside it, using WebdriveJS. Looking for a Div that contains the text, "TestIt". This seems pretty straightforward.

```
driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'TestIt')]")).then(function(foundIt)
{
    console.log(foundIt);
}
```

But foundIt always equals false.

This is the div:

```
<div class="v-table-cell-wrapper">TestIt</div>
```

I actually want to be able to find the string using a variable, but I can't get the basic part to work. Any thoughts from anyone?

Comment: Might be its under a frame / iframe...please check...

Comment: I think that's it. We didn't write the original code, and it's... well..... I'm also new to Selenium, which doesn't help.

Comment: Nope. Iframes, but not around this content.

Answer (score 3):

Should be as easy as(Assuming there is not `iframe` involved)

```
 //div[.='TestIt']
```

Just in case if it has white spaces before or after

```
//div[contains(.,'TestIt')]
```

Comment: Can you provide the `stacktrace`?

Comment: Not getting an error. It's just not finding it. Always comes back false.

Comment: This thing is buried so deep, layer after layer of divs, headers, nav. Does that layer need to be defined, as in //div//div//div.... it's a pretty crazy page.

Comment: can you provide more `html` then?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I learned something very good today. I was using Phantom to test, but the problem is of course that you can't see what's going on. I had started on Chrome. I moved back to Chrome I realized that I was no longer getting as far as I was before in my script, hence the inability to find the element. I feel a bit stupid, but live and learn. Thanks for replying, guys.